# ArcGIS 10.2 Polygon topology

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, topology

I did a topology check on a polygon layer. It turns out I have line errors "Must not have gaps". I don't understand as there are no gaps in the polygons.

I attached an image, the errors are the red lines. There is only one big polygon because I merged the islands with a Country.

Any idea on what could cause this error and how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix try tool [Repair Geometry](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/repair-geometry.htm):

> Inspects each feature in a feature class for geometry problems. Upon
>   discovery of a geometry problem, a relevant fix will be applied, and a
>   one-line description will be printed identifying the feature as well
>   as the problem encountered.